How can I progress from here on Minesweeper Advent Day 43? (Everyone's Favorite Shape Even Better)
It has honestly been some time (11 months, 2 weeks, and 1 day) since I have last posted one of my Minesweeper puzzles, and I would honestly like to get back into doing that with some more interesting concepts. And so, I have been replaying the 2022 and 2023 Heptaveegesimal Minesweeper Advent Calendar to try to reteach myself Minesweeper solving methods so I can make good puzzles based off that.
I am currently stuck on Day 43: Everyone's Favorite Shape Even Better. The main gimmick here is that it is the exact same as Day 6 (from the 2022 calendar), where numbers see mines a knight's path away from them, except the layout is different and there are big mines.
Which admittedly, I don't really understand how big mines work at all, even though I've been able to almost get through really any of the days involving big mines.
This is the layout for Day 43:

Note that the portion shaped like a knight has a lower chance of spawning mines.
While I have been able to make some progress, I have no clue on what to do next, especially with the big mines as I have never really understood how they work or how they work here.
Here is my current progress:

My question: What can I next deduce about this, and have I made any mistakes?

Partial solution:

 Legend:  Gold: Marked because there must be a mine (or a large mine in particular) in the remaining cells it can refer to.  Light blue: Already saturated cells that can lead to no more mines.  Light green: Safe cells.  Orange: Cells with any sort of mine.  Red: Cells with small mines.  Burgundy: Cells with large mines.    Click the safe cells to open up the board.

Introducing a new technique:

 Slashed burgundy marks: Cells that can't contain large mines:  

Some more safe cells:

 Purple and brown pairs of dots: If cells a and b are examined, it can be seen that these symmetrical pairs get 1 mine out of them each, so some more cells can be ruled out:  

